# set margin for a group of buttons

Tags: java, swing, margin, jbutton

Is there a way to collectively change the padding of JButtons? I found the setMargin() method, but that doesn't work on button groups and I really can't imagine going through 25 buttons individually. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your button group is called `buttonGroup`, you can use:

```
buttonGroup.getElements();
```

Which returns an `Enumeration` containing the buttons. You can then invoke `setMargin()` on each button...

Answer (score 1):

Several possible solutions are available:
1)  Have the buttons in an array or collection and change them as you iterate through.
2)  Create the JButtons in a "factory" method. I think that I like this one best.
3)  Subclass JButton (my least favorite option).
4)  Probably more...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for all buttons in the application, then you can use the UIManager:

```
UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
```

If you want to do this on specify buttons in an application then you need to do each individual button. However, I don't understand the problem, since somewhere in your code you must create the 25 buttons. So at that point you set the margin on the button as well.